# How to prevent so many DESCRIBE queries in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Unfortunately, the CakePHP documentation is horrible.  I can't seem to figure out if it's possible to cache the results of these DESCRIBE queries in my live environment.  All I can find on caching for CakePHP is caching for data within controllers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your debug to 0 in your core.php file.  With debugging > 0, Cake automatically checks for schema changes.